# Installing Dropbox fails at 99%, causing dpkg errors...how do I fix?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, dpkg, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox fails to install, stuck at 99%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-fails-to-install-stuck-at-99)

I've run a script (`ubuntu-12.04-postinstall.py`) that auto-installs suggested programs. All of it worked fine until it tried to install dropbox. It got to 99% and froze for quite a while. So, I closed the terminal and rebooted. Now whenever I try to use `apt-get install`, it gives this error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem"
```

I did this and eventually was able to install software but then it tried to install dropbox again automatically and still got stuck at 99%.

How can i get this cleared from `dpkg`? I really don't want to have to run through hoops every time just to install new software!

In case this matters, this is a Lubuntu system. I'd strongly prefer not to reinstall Lubuntu as it was a pain to install originally; I had installed a horrible copy of the distro, and it took over 15 hours to fix and install.

edit: ran this to check what might be going on.

> sudo dpkg --configure -a --dry-run 
>   got back: 
>   [pastebin] http://paste.ubuntu.com/1055407/ 
>   how can i just clear this out?