# How to update dropbox in Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: updates, xubuntu, dropbox

I tried to find a way to update my dropbox installation but none of the solutions I found on Internet work.

My system is Xubuntu 12.04 and has `dropbox` 1.4.0 installed.

The `.deb` file on the Dropbox web site is the same version.

Comment: If the .deb file on official dropbox site is same as installed then where did you got the idea of newer version not yet released.
try **sudo dropbox update** and post if it works out.In my Dropbox preferences > Account it shows version 1.4.3.

Comment: I don't know why but download remains "forever" in 99%.

Comment: There seems to be a bug but also a workaround for that [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-install-stuck-at-99-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have latest version of Dropbox, and a newer version is not released yet, you don't have to do anything right now. After the release of a newer version, just try to manually download the .deb of Dropbox and install it with the Ubuntu Software Center or use:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```