# Dropbox 99% instalation crash. Strange "Searching" Ubuntu Software Center bug

Tags: installation, process, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox fails to install, stuck at 99%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-fails-to-install-stuck-at-99)

I just installed Dropbox via Ubuntu Software Center, and the known crash of 99%, which was in Ubuntu Software center, happened. I want to remove Dropbox completely since something went wrong, but I can't. When I start my Ubuntu, it starts a process which eats up all of the CPU. In Ubuntu Software Center, there is a process "Searching Applying Changes", but nothing really happens. When I'm trying to uninstall Dropbox, nothing happens, since the seaching thing is "first".

Please, I'm asking for a option which doesn't include proper reinstallation of Dropbox, only of getting rid of it, and without reinstalling the whole Ubuntu system (format, chaos etc).