# My top panel and launcher is gone after trying to install Dropbox

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit, dropbox

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 and when I tried to install Dropbox it froze at 99%. Then I hit the reset button and I lost the control panel on top and the launcher. I then tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and nothing happened. Any advice?

Comment: Did you reboot the computer?

Comment: Attempting to load Dropbox to Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit) will likely lockup **Software Centre** and/or give you 100% CPU (which could stop you shutting down normally).  **What happened after you forced a restart?**

Comment: Yes, I did restart the computer, several times. Now I have lost my Home and Computer icons. All I have now is an empty top panel w/o any control buttons. The only thing left is the get Help on line option.I tried using the unity --reset and --reset-icons also.

Answer (score 1):

**This is two separate issues.**

***STEP 1***

To force recovery of your GUI, then remove and re-install from text-console mode.  This should fully recover, but will not affect any files, folders you have (presumably also backed-up).

***STEP 2***

Once you re-start your machine, and resolve any issues with 'control panel' and 'launcher' then follow instructions at:

[Dropbox install stuck at 99%, how do I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-install-stuck-at-99-how-do-i-fix-it)