# Ubuntu 12.04 Dropbox installation issue (stuck at 99%)

Tags: dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox install stuck at 99%, how do I fix it? (and any dpkg errors)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-install-stuck-at-99-how-do-i-fix-it-and-any-dpkg-errors)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Yes, I read this post: [Dropbox install stuck at 99%, how do I fix it? (and any dpkg errors)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-install-stuck-at-99-how-do-i-fix-it-and-any-dpkg-errors)

I even tried to use 64 and 32-bit versions, tried to download it with wget, tried to compile it from sources. I haven't any effect: it load my Core i5 for about 100%, and there is no progress after 99%. How can I to fix it?