# Stuck since I try to install dropbox

Tags: updates, software-center, dropbox

First of all I apologize for my english, but I'm stuck and I don't know much of linux.

When I try to install Dropbox in my ubuntu it get stuck and I try to close it, but know I have a serching (applying changes) on the progress tab in ubuntu software center. Since I was trying to solve this I first use the comand `sudo apt-get update` and I get this:

```
[sudo] password for mel: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

then I use this comands that I found in other fourum `sudo killall -9 dpkg` and update again, it works but at the end I get this:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

when I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get this

```
Setting up nautilus-dropbox (0.7.1-2) ...

Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/

Downloading Dropbox... 100%
```

And it get stuck again, please help

Comment: There is something else open trying to install something. Close everything else, then install. If it is still broken: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Comment: @Tim Given the information provided in the edit, I think this is the same problem as [nautilus-dropbox 0.7.1-2 installation process freeze](http://askubuntu.com/q/508958/22949) (no solution there though, and I'm not convinced that's really the same as the fixed bug [Dropbox install stuck at 99%, how do I fix it? (and any dpkg errors)](http://askubuntu.com/q/154671/22949))

Comment: I had the same problem as you, but I think I fixed it with https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966990. Apparently you have to close dropbox, as it was already installed in my computer and I failed to update it, I had to close it manually in gnome and then it worked! I write it here down because maybe someone will have the same problem